# Advantages of using Angular 2 Button component over html/css button

Tags: angular

Is there an advantage by using Angular 2 button/tabs/any other html component over creating this component in plain html/css as a globally reusable code?

Will it be an extra overhead using Angular 2 button component over the normal buttons?

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is that you don't need to build it yourself ;-).

The disadvantage is that it might contain more code (TS, HTML, CSS) and probably several imports of components it is built of than what might be necessary for your current use case because they are built in a generic way so that they can be used in many use cases.

Another disadvantage is that it might be limited how you can customize it while you are only limited to what the browser allows if you build it yourself.

If you care about the additional code, HTML, CSS then I'm pretty sure it's a case of premature optimization but without knowing more details about your concrete requirements it's hard to tell.